# SQL Server CE Incompatible Database Version

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server CE 4.0 database (`.sdf` file) and when I trying doing a query on the database from my application (WPF) I get the following error.

> Incompatible Database Version. If this was a compatible file, run repair. For other cases refer to documentation. [ Db version = 4000000,Requested version = 3505053,File name = \?\C:\Database\ShortageReport\MRPDatabase.sdf]

- I have checked SQL Server CE 4 sp1 is installed.
- I have tried creating the database in both Database.Net 4 and in the connection setup in vs2012.
- I'm running windows 7 64bit
- My connection string is stored in the `app.config`.

I am using SQL Server Compact Toolbox to generate the context and the mappings.

My `app.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseContext" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
         connectionString="Data Source=C:\Database\ShortageReport\MRPDatabase.sdf"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/03/15/sql-server-compact-4-0-tooling-support-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1-and-visual-web-developer-express-2010-sp1.aspx) link

Comment: In my case, it's "...Db version = 0, Requested version = 0..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a reference to the version 4.0 System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll ADO.NET provider

Then initialize the `DataContext` class with a `SqlCeConnection` (4.0) object.

```
using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\projects\Chinook\Chinook40.sdf"))
{
    using (Chinook db = new Chinook(conn))
    {
        var list = db.Album.ToList();
        if (list.Count > 0)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("It works!");
    }
}
```

Comment: System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll is not in the list of Assemblies to add as a reference. Where is the file located? and I will try and browse for it.

Comment: Scratch that, I found it. Will try now.

Comment: I would like to add comment related to the issue from link [Incompatible Database Version 3.5 vs 4.0](https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/workitem/11450) as *The LInq To Sql runtime is hardcoded to v 3.5, but if you initialze the DataContext with SqlCeConnection object instead of connection string, it will Work with 4.* (comment by [ErikEJ](http://stackoverflow.com/users/183934/erikej))

Answer (score 2):

I updated SqlServerCe.dll reference from following path, and it fixed

Reference Path:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found on similar problem and uninstalling all frameworks SQL Server Compact 3.5 and SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP1 I've solved this issue.

Cheers,