# SqlServerCe version problems

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I am writing a simple console app in Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.0.
In the solution I have 2 projects:

- console app project (this is the starting project), call it A
- library project (here I have my DB file and DataContext generated), call it B

My database is a SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 file (DataStore.sdf).
Project B is included as a reference in project A.
I have used SQL Server Compact Toolbox to generate the DataContext in project B.
When I run the application I get the following error (which you have seen in other posts probably):

> Incompatible Database Version. 
>   If this was a compatible file, run repair. 
>   For other cases refer to documentation. 
>   [ Db version = 4000000,
>     Requested version = 3505053,
>     File name = \?\C:\workspace\projects\mytestapp\bin\Debug\DataStore.sdf ]

I went through the following 2 posts:
[Post_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223359/cant-get-sql-server-compact-3-5-4-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-2)
[Post_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543400/sqlce-incompatible-database-version)
I have both versions of SqlServerCe installed on my PC: 3.5 and 4.0. Both x86 and x64.
I have tried to copy files as suggested in Post_1 to both /bin directories of project A and B, and reference System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll from respective folders in both projects. I have also tried the same but with files in /bin/debug, no luck.
Am I missing something?
Thanks for help...

Comment: see my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/10/sql-server-compact-4-desktop-app-with.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataContext must be constructed with a SqlCeConnection object (not a connection string), in order for LINQ to SQL to work with SQL Server Compact 4.0.

Comment: Thanks, your blog and answer helped. You are like a SqlServerCe helpline from what I can see around the internet ;)

Comment: You legend - I've wasted 5 precious hours today and this is what fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if in your console app's app.config, you refer to CE3.5, whereas your Datastore.sdf is actually 4.0. Try to remove any SQL-CE *reference* from your console application, and add a new reference to SQL-CE4.0.

Do check if indeed this is the problem first. If your DataStore is actually 3.5, then you should remove the reference and add a 3.5 reference to your console application.

If i am not mistaken, you can add the reference easiest using nuget.