# Incompatible Database Versions when syncing

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to sync two CE databases as some spike work. I'm following the tutorial here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928606(v=sql.110).aspx to do so.

When I try to synchronize the two databases I get the following error:

> Incompatible Database Version. If this was a compatible file, run repair. For other cases refer to documentation. [ Db version = 4000000,Requested version = 3505053,File name = C:\Projects\DataBase Spike\DataBase Spike\Local.sdf ]

This is my code

```
SqlCeConnection clientConn = new SqlCeConnection(@"DataSource='Local.sdf'");
SqlCeConnection serverConn = new SqlCeConnection(@"DataSource='Server.sdf'");

SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();

syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlCeSyncProvider("ProductsScope", clientConn);
syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlCeSyncProvider("ProductsScope", serverConn);

syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;

syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
```

From this question here - [SQL Server CE Incompatible Database Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543400/sql-server-ce-incompatible-database-version) I've ensured that my `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` is version 4.0, and I'm using `SqlCeConnection`

Comment: The other database have been created in SQL CE 3.5. Both db's must be created with same versions of SQL CE.

Comment: @raidensan I just re-created both databases through visual studio and I'm still having the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL CE 4 is not supported in Sync Fx. But you can get away with some assembly binding redirect... check out this [post](https://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/sync-framework-and-sql-compact-4-yes-you-can/)